# How to play one video in jQuery tab and stop others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have 4 Jquery tabs, In each tab there is 2 videos. how I make one video play at the time and pause all others? and How make the video pause when I switch to new Tab?

this is the code [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamadhus/TKUcY/2/)

```
/* play one video at a time */

$('video').bind('play', function() {
  activated = this;
  $('video').each(function() {
      if(this != activated) {
          this.pause();
      }
  });
});

/* get the active tab */
var active = $( "#issuestabs" ).tabs( "option", "active" ); 


/* pause all videos that are not in the active tab*/ 

if (!active) {
    $("video").each(function(){
        $(this).get(0).pause();
    });

}
```

can anyone show me what is wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you use:

```
$('.tab').on('click', function() {
  $('.tabcontent:hidden').find('video').each(function() {
    $(this).get(0).pause();
  });
});
```

(where `.tabcontent` is the name of your content panels that are hidden/shown, the click function i showed is just an example since I do not know which library you are using for tabs.)

Comment: Thank you Simey.me. I am using Jquery UI latest version.

Comment: I still can not makes it work. the content panels has attribute `aria-hidden="true"` how do I get hold it instead of tab content ?

Comment: It now works, I was forgetting to put it after the DOM ready. Thanks!